# Jar files are not working

Tags: netbeans, jar, java

I am not sure if such question has been asked before. My problem is that after uninstalling the old 32-bit JRE6 and JDK6 and installing the new 64 JRE7 and JDK7 my jar files are not working. I am using Netbeans 7.1.

1. Running programs from Netbeans using Run button in Netbeans works.
2. Running jar files using command line works.
3. Running jar files using double clicking does not work.

Just to avoid confusion I had already set jar files to open with javaw.exe, my jar files used to work by double clicking and now after clicking the jar file nothing happens. I already tried the reinstall solution but as you can guess did not work.

I hope I can find a fulfilling answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "not working mean"? Java stacktrace? Error from netbeans? OS level error?

Comment: As I said the jar file won't run by double clicking or maybe it javaw.exe exits when I run it for some unknown reason

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean that double clicking the jar file does not work? What happens when you do this?

Comment: Nothing happens, I double click it and nothing happens. Literally nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved, I used [jarfix](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Jarfix-Download-79716.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you on `windows`? If yes then try the follwoing in a command window:

```
start /b <jar file>
```

I am assuming the jar file "executes" but gets an error. The above should help you identify the error

Comment: Yes I am on windows I tried the above line on the command line but it show nothing nor does it launch the app. I am also thinking it is an error in the javaw.exe

Comment: Have you tried printing to System.err to see if anything is displayed? You could also try modifying System.err to print to a file and see if there is any output: `System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("error.log")));`

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue once. This happens when you have not clean installed latest version of java and the file association is not properly set to reflect the newer javaw.exe

In your command prompt type -

```
C:\Documents and Settings\XYZ>assoc .jar
.jar=jarfile
```

Then associate your jarfile to javaw.exe of jre7-

```
C:\Documents and Settings\XYZ>ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when I print assoc .jar it says "File association not found for extension .jar"